# insert checkbox while looping

Tags: dart, flutter

am creating checkbox like this:

```
 for (var a in user.poll.questions[i].options) {
        children.add(
          new Row(
            children: [
              new Checkbox(
                value: checkBoxValue,
                onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    checkBoxValue = newValue;
                  });
                }
              ),
              new Text(a.text),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
```

and this will create this:

[image]

Which is what i need .. but the problem is when one checked all will be updated and be checked and reverse ...

i want to check one .. and only this one will be checked and i get its value ..

how to do this? is there is checkbox id or something?

Comment: You need one variable for each field

Comment: @RémiRousselet how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save selected question - something like:

```
Question selectedQuestion = null;
.....

 for (var a in user.poll.questions[i].options) {
    children.add(
      new Row(
        children: [
          new Checkbox(
            value: selectedQuestion == a,
            onChanged: (bool newValue) {
              setState(() {
                selectedQuestion = a;
              });
            }
          ),
          new Text(a.text),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**UPD**
For multiple checking:

1 - set list instead of one value

```
final List<Question> questionList = [];
```

2 - change CheckBox behavior

```
Checkbox(
        value: questionList.contains(a),
        onChanged: (bool newValue) {
          setState(() {
            newValue ? questionList.add(a) : questionList.remove(a);
          });
        }
      )
```

Comment: what if i want multiple checkboxes to be checked?

Comment: this now allow only one to be checked

Comment: Update the answer

Comment: Vote up on the answer would be enough :D

Comment: sure thing!! :)